# Beautify scaleBand

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I just tried out d3js for some days and I want to beautify the x and y scales of my graph to be something like this

[image]

But this is what I got so far.

[image]

I have tried changing from `scaleBand()` to `scaleLinear()` and fix the normally `bandwidth()` method to a constant value, the graph just would not show.

This is the code

```
  mounted () {
    this.generateChart()
  },
  methods: {
    generateChart () {
      // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
      const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 30 }
      const width = 1850 - margin.left - margin.right
      const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom

      // make the area for the graph to stay
      const svg = d3.select('#heatmap')
        .append('svg') // svg area can include headers and color scales
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right) // set width
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom) // set height
        .append('g') // new g tag area for graph only
        .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.bottom})`)
        // stick g tag to the bottom

      // range function generate graph scales
      // TODO: make a range using date and time
      const xLabel = d3.range(259)
      const yLabel = d3.range(23, -1, -1)

      // create x, y scales and axes
      const x = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(xLabel)
        .range([0, width])
        .padding(0.05)

      svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

      const y = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(yLabel)
        .range([height, 0])
        .padding(0.05)
      svg.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y))

      d3.json('../predictions.json').then(function (data) {
        svg.selectAll()
          .data(data.heatmaps.kw.Sand_Heads)
          .enter()
          .append('rect')
          .attr('x', function (d) {
            return x(d[1]) // return cell's position
          })
          .attr('y', function (d) {
            return y(d[0])
          })
          .attr('cx', 1)
          .attr('cy', 1)
          .attr('width', x.bandwidth()) // return cell's width
          .attr('height', y.bandwidth()) // return cell's height
          .style('fill', function (d) {
            return rgbaToHex(0, 128, 255, 100 * d[2])
          })
          .on('mouseover', function () { // box stroke when hover
            d3.select(this)
              .style('stroke', 'black')
              .style('opacity', 1)
          })
          .on('mouseout', function () { // fade block stroke when mouse leave the cell
            d3.select(this)
              .style('stroke', 'none')
              .style('opacity', 0.8)
          })
      })
    }
```

Note: I have to make it work with date selection in the future too.

This is the structure of the data I'm working on.

```
{
  "days": ["2019-04-11", "2019-04-12", ..., "2019-12-25"],
  "heatmaps": {
    "kw": {
      "Tilly_Point": [[5, 112, 0.0012], [6, 112, 0.0016], ...],
      "Mouat_Point": [...]
    },
    "hw": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation:
the first element of subarray in `Tilly_Point` is the time of the whale found. ranging from 0 to 23 (midnight to next midnight) and 5 means 05:00 A.M. to 06:00 A.M.

the second element is the nth day of the operation. It's 112 meaning it's the 112th day of the operation. which is 1 August 2019

the last element is the real data being plotted on the graph. the higher -> darker colour towards the real color with 1 opacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the desired design we can understand what you mean by *"beautify"* is reducing the number of ticks. And you are absolutely correct: in very few and specific situations we need to show all of them; most of the times, the design is cleaner and the user benefits from a more tidy dataviz if we choose what ticks to display.

That's clear if we look at this basic example I wrote, simulating your axes:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(25))
  .range([10, 80])
  .paddingInner(1);
const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(261))
  .range([25, 490])
  .paddingInner(1);
d3.axisLeft(yScale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(25,0)"));
d3.axisBottom(xScale)(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,80)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

There are different approaches for reducing the number of ticks here: you can explicitly chose the ticks to show by value or, as I'll do in this answer, you can simply choose how many of them to show. Here, I'll do this using the remainder operator (`%`) filtering the scale's domain and passing it to `tickValues` (since you have a band scale we cannot use `ticks`), for instance showing every 6th value for the y axis:

```
.tickValues(yScale.domain().filter((_, i) => !(i % 6)))
```

Here is the result:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(25))
  .range([10, 80])
  .paddingInner(1);
const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(261))
  .range([25, 490])
  .paddingInner(1);
d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickValues(yScale.domain().filter((_, i) => !(i % 6)))(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(25,0)"));
d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickValues(xScale.domain().filter((_, i) => !(i % 20)))(svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,80)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Is there any way to change them completely to be date just like the example? Or the data would not sync

Comment: That's a different question (which, by the way, is a duplicate).